# CNN loss function increases exponentially

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to classify objects vs background from microscopy images. I have preprocessed the data in a function that I built that resizes the entire image and mask to `1500x1500` then splits them up into images of size `150x150`. Then I binarize the masks using `cv2`. Lastly, I pad the images by `5` pixels all around to get `160x160` images. I then use those folders in the CNN.

(I have used the Oxford Pets Example CNN to build mine)
My entire CNN is below:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

"""
## Prepare paths of input images and target segmentation masks
"""

import os

input_dir = "/Users/msshah/Downloads/8_22_pre1/split_images/"
target_dir = "/Users/msshah/Downloads/8_22_pre1/split_masks/"
img_size = (160,160)
num_classes = 2 # change from 3 to 2 
batch_size = 4

input_img_paths = sorted(
    [
        os.path.join(input_dir, fname)
        for fname in os.listdir(input_dir)
        if fname.endswith(".jpg")
    ]
)
target_img_paths = sorted(
    [
        os.path.join(target_dir, fname)
        for fname in os.listdir(target_dir)
        if fname.endswith(".png") and not fname.startswith(".")
    ]
)

print("Number of samples:", len(input_img_paths)) # it's 270

for input_path, target_path in zip(input_img_paths[:10], target_img_paths[:10]):
    print(input_path, "|", target_path)

"""
## What does one input image and corresponding segmentation mask look like?
"""

from IPython.display import Image, display
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
import PIL
from PIL import ImageOps

# Display input image #7
display(Image(filename=input_img_paths[9]))

# Display auto-contrast version of corresponding target (per-pixel categories)
img = PIL.ImageOps.autocontrast(load_img(target_img_paths[9]))
display(img)

"""
## Prepare `Sequence` class to load & vectorize batches of data
"""

from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img


class OxfordPets(keras.utils.Sequence):
    """Helper to iterate over the data (as Numpy arrays)."""

    def __init__(self, batch_size, img_size, input_img_paths, target_img_paths):
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.img_size = img_size
        self.input_img_paths = input_img_paths
        self.target_img_paths = target_img_paths

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.target_img_paths) // self.batch_size

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        """Returns tuple (input, target) correspond to batch #idx."""
        i = idx * self.batch_size
        batch_input_img_paths = self.input_img_paths[i : i + self.batch_size]
        batch_target_img_paths = self.target_img_paths[i : i + self.batch_size]
        x = np.zeros((self.batch_size,) + self.img_size + (3,), dtype="float32")
        for j, path in enumerate(batch_input_img_paths):
            img = load_img(path, target_size=self.img_size)
            x[j] = img
        y = np.zeros((self.batch_size,) + self.img_size + (1,), dtype="uint8")
        for j, path in enumerate(batch_target_img_paths):
            img = load_img(path, target_size=self.img_size, color_mode="grayscale")
            y[j] = np.expand_dims(img, 2)
            # Ground truth labels are 1, 2, 3. Subtract one to make them 0, 1, 2:
            y[j] -= 0
        return x, y
    


"""
## Prepare U-Net Xception-style model
"""

from tensorflow.keras import layers


def get_model(img_size, num_classes):
    inputs = keras.Input(shape=img_size + (3,))

    ### [First half of the network: downsampling inputs] ###

    # Entry block
    x = layers.Conv2D(32, 3, strides=2, padding="same")(inputs)
    x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = layers.Activation("relu")(x)

    previous_block_activation = x  # Set aside residual

    # Blocks 1, 2, 3 are identical apart from the feature depth.
    for filters in [64, 128, 256]:
        x = layers.Activation("relu")(x)
        x = layers.SeparableConv2D(filters, 3, padding="same")(x)
        x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

        x = layers.Activation("relu")(x)
        x = layers.SeparableConv2D(filters, 3, padding="same")(x)
        x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

        x = layers.MaxPooling2D(3, strides=2, padding="same")(x)

        # Project residual
        residual = layers.Conv2D(filters, 1, strides=2, padding="same")(
            previous_block_activation
        )
        x = layers.add([x, residual])  # Add back residual
        previous_block_activation = x  # Set aside next residual

    ### [Second half of the network: upsampling inputs] ###

    for filters in [256, 128, 64, 32]:
        x = layers.Activation("relu")(x)
        x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters, 3, padding="same")(x)
        x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

        x = layers.Activation("relu")(x)
        x = layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters, 3, padding="same")(x)
        x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)

        x = layers.UpSampling2D(2)(x)

        # Project residual
        residual = layers.UpSampling2D(2)(previous_block_activation)
        residual = layers.Conv2D(filters, 1, padding="same")(residual)
        x = layers.add([x, residual])  # Add back residual
        previous_block_activation = x  # Set aside next residual

    # Add a per-pixel classification layer
    outputs = layers.Conv2D(num_classes, 3, activation="softmax", padding="same")(x)

    # Define the model
    model = keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
    return model


# Free up RAM in case the model definition cells were run multiple times
keras.backend.clear_session()

# Build model
model = get_model(img_size, num_classes)
model.summary()

"""
## Set aside a validation split
"""

import random

# Split our img paths into a training and a validation set
val_samples = 80
random.Random(251).shuffle(input_img_paths)
random.Random(251).shuffle(target_img_paths)
train_input_img_paths = input_img_paths[:-val_samples]
train_target_img_paths = target_img_paths[:-val_samples]
val_input_img_paths = input_img_paths[-val_samples:]
val_target_img_paths = target_img_paths[-val_samples:]


#print("Number of validation samples:", len(val_input_img_paths)) # it's 20

# Instantiate data Sequences for each split
train_gen = OxfordPets(
    batch_size, img_size, train_input_img_paths, train_target_img_paths
)
val_gen = OxfordPets(batch_size, img_size, val_input_img_paths, val_target_img_paths)

"""
## Train the model
"""

# Configure the model for training.
# We use the "sparse" version of categorical_crossentropy
# because our target data is integers.
model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop",  loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy")

callbacks = [
    keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint('/Users/msshah/Desktop/myc.h5', metric="val_loss", monitor='loss',save_best_only=True)
]

# Train the model, doing validation at the end of each epoch.
epochs = 100

model.fit(train_gen, epochs=epochs, validation_data=val_gen, callbacks=callbacks)

"""
## Visualize predictions
"""

# Generate predictions for all images in the validation set

val_gen = OxfordPets(batch_size, img_size, val_input_img_paths, val_target_img_paths)
val_preds = model.predict(val_gen)


def display_mask(i):
    """Quick utility to display a model's prediction."""
    mask = np.argmax(val_preds[i], axis=-1)
    mask = np.expand_dims(mask, axis=-1)
    img = PIL.ImageOps.autocontrast(keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img(mask))
    display(img)


# Display results for validation image #10
i = 55

# Display input image
display(Image(filename=val_input_img_paths[i]))

# Display ground-truth target mask
img = PIL.ImageOps.autocontrast(load_img(val_target_img_paths[i]))
display(img)

# Display mask predicted by our model
display_mask(i)  # Note that the model only sees inputs at 150x150.


# # visualized new masks
# mask = np.argmax(val_preds[i], axis=-1)
# display(mask)
# mask = np.expand_dims(mask, axis=-1)
# img = PIL.ImageOps.autocontrast(keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img(mask))
# ar=np.array(display_mask(i))
```

Example Image and Corresponding Mask:

[image]

[image: Mask]

The resulting loss (I aborted to avoid wasting time):

```
Epoch 1/100
2022-08-22 14:42:33.774697: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/custom_graph_optimizer_registry.cc:113] Plugin optimizer for device_type GPU is enabled.
140/140 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 4566116.50002022-08-22 14:42:49.327210: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/custom_graph_optimizer_registry.cc:113] Plugin optimizer for device_type GPU is enabled.
140/140 [==============================] - 19s 100ms/step - loss: 4566116.5000 - val_loss: 12855079.0000
Epoch 2/100
 19/140 [===>..........................] - ETA: 9s - loss: 52523544.0000
```

How can I improve/adapt this CNN to fit my needs? I have tried looking at the background, contrast, type, and format of the data, but nothing helped.

EDIT: After @DrSnoopy's suggestion, I ran the model for 150 epochs and it still was increasing:

```
 conv2d_7 (Conv2D)              (None, 160, 160, 32  2080        ['up_sampling2d_7[0][0]']        
                                )                                                                 
                                                                                                  
 add_6 (Add)                    (None, 160, 160, 32  0           ['up_sampling2d_6[0][0]',        
                                )                                 'conv2d_7[0][0]']               
                                                                                                  
 conv2d_8 (Conv2D)              (None, 160, 160, 2)  578         ['add_6[0][0]']                  
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 2,058,690
Trainable params: 2,054,914
Non-trainable params: 3,776
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
2022-08-23 09:39:23.425799: W tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:128] Failed to get CPU frequency: 0 Hz
Epoch 1/300
2022-08-23 09:39:25.387676: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/custom_graph_optimizer_registry.cc:113] Plugin optimizer for device_type GPU is enabled.
140/140 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 5569157.50002022-08-23 09:39:49.073162: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/custom_graph_optimizer_registry.cc:113] Plugin optimizer for device_type GPU is enabled.
140/140 [==============================] - 27s 137ms/step - loss: 5569157.5000 - val_loss: 6859.2861
Epoch 2/300
140/140 [==============================] - 18s 129ms/step - loss: 571536640.0000 - val_loss: 3613500.0000
Epoch 3/300
140/140 [==============================] - 18s 131ms/step - loss: 3728208896.0000 - val_loss: 646872000.0000
Epoch 4/300
140/140 [==============================] - 18s 130ms/step - loss: 47146336256.0000 - val_loss: 422472810496.0000
Epoch 5/300
140/140 [==============================] - 18s 128ms/step - loss: 223554125824.0000 - val_loss: 1839579791360.0000
Epoch 6/300
140/140 [==============================] - 18s 131ms/step - loss: 1108649050112.0000 - val_loss: 183316938752.0000
Epoch 7/300
140/140 [==============================] - 18s 129ms/step - loss: 3697384095744.0000 - val_loss: 56803905536.0000
Epoch 8/300
140/140 [==============================] - 18s 129ms/step - loss: 5855387320320.0000 - val_loss: 717628571648.0000
Epoch 9/300
140/140 [==============================] - 18s 130ms/step - loss: 14110851858432.0000 - val_loss: 997670060032.0000
Epoch 10/300
140/140 [==============================] - 18s 130ms/step - loss: 31986372575232.0000 - val_loss: 486142476288.0000
Epoch 11/300
140/140 [==============================] - 18s 130ms/step - loss: 64187753562112.0000 - val_loss: 892020981760.0000
Epoch 12/300
140/140 [==============================] - 18s 130ms/step - loss: 124633290375168.0000 - val_loss: 1562812481536.0000
Epoch 13/300
140/140 [==============================] - 18s 129ms/step - loss: 255640177999872.0000 - val_loss: 18552289492992.0000
Epoch 14/300
140/140 [==============================] - 18s 130ms/step - loss: 444414728077312.0000 - val_loss: 2206558775672832.0000
Epoch 15/300
140/140 [==============================] - 18s 128ms/step - loss: 828913320198144.0000 - val_loss: 6888240971776.0000
Epoch 16/300
140/140 [==============================] - 18s 132ms/step - loss: 1224680799207424.0000 - val_loss: 7479050964566016.0000
Epoch 17/300
140/140 [==============================] - 18s 131ms/step - loss: 2077974836805632.0000 - val_loss: 74734066728960.0000
Epoch 18/300
140/140 [==============================] - 18s 131ms/step - loss: 2526454650765312.0000 - val_loss: 183863456301056.0000
Epoch 19/300
140/140 [==============================] - 18s 131ms/step - loss: 4801047587454976.0000 - val_loss: 38766651637760.0000
Epoch 20/300
140/140 [==============================] - 18s 130ms/step - loss: 5237967094284288.0000 - val_loss: 48318532403855360.0000
Epoch 21/300
140/140 [==============================] - 18s 132ms/step - loss: 10051794356928512.0000 - val_loss: 126613077360640.0000
Epoch 22/300
140/140 [==============================] - 18s 132ms/step - loss: 12745147947155456.0000 - val_loss: 110261373501440.0000
Epoch 23/300
140/140 [==============================] - 18s 132ms/step - loss: 15661542410289152.0000 - val_loss: 111887186395136.0000
Epoch 24/300
140/140 [==============================] - 18s 130ms/step - loss: 25841233377099776.0000 - val_loss: 191708197289984.0000
Epoch 25/300
140/140 [==============================] - 18s 130ms/step - loss: 39912083109707776.0000 - val_loss: 117047127355424768.0000
Epoch 26/300
140/140 [==============================] - 18s 129ms/step - loss: 48233775519236096.0000 - val_loss: 1657659807760384.0000
Epoch 27/300
140/140 [==============================] - 18s 129ms/step - loss: 65457522089132032.0000 - val_loss: 787842292776960.0000
Epoch 28/300
140/140 [==============================] - 18s 129ms/step - loss: 92925122142273536.0000 - val_loss: 446353033396224.0000
Epoch 29/300
140/140 [==============================] - 18s 131ms/step - loss: 108110571722768384.0000 - val_loss: 376364192497664.0000
Epoch 30/300
140/140 [==============================] - 18s 130ms/step - loss: 122574595646554112.0000 - val_loss: 656591112110080.0000
Epoch 31/300
140/140 [==============================] - 18s 130ms/step - loss: 152561206903701504.0000 - val_loss: 1886098649251840.0000
Epoch 32/300
140/140 [==============================] - 18s 131ms/step - loss: 216618857417146368.0000 - val_loss: 1736308040925184.0000
Epoch 33/300
140/140 [==============================] - 18s 131ms/step - loss: 283544893249290240.0000 - val_loss: 2403450779579973632.0000
Epoch 34/300
140/140 [==============================] - 18s 131ms/step - loss: 2053721282112913408.0000 - val_loss: 2279197856743030784.0000
Epoch 35/300
140/140 [==============================] - 18s 131ms/step - loss: 2589084626232279040.0000 - val_loss: 2655814261799911424.0000
Epoch 36/300
140/140 [==============================] - 18s 131ms/step - loss: 3038755195178713088.0000 - val_loss: 3055211035955822592.0000
Epoch 37/300
140/140 [==============================] - 19s 132ms/step - loss: 3540261140305018880.0000 - val_loss: 3608527343372468224.0000
Epoch 38/300
140/140 [==============================] - 15s 110ms/step - loss: 4088988910821048320.0000 - val_loss: 4181661798123962368.0000
Epoch 39/300
140/140 [==============================] - 11s 80ms/step - loss: 4708659095706533888.0000 - val_loss: 4668411472571793408.0000
Epoch 40/300
140/140 [==============================] - 11s 80ms/step - loss: 5395485526671228928.0000 - val_loss: 5363031791709978624.0000
Epoch 41/300
140/140 [==============================] - 11s 81ms/step - loss: 6202682642354143232.0000 - val_loss: 6165587868812050432.0000
Epoch 42/300
140/140 [==============================] - 11s 81ms/step - loss: 7052420412671524864.0000 - val_loss: 7099680171212406784.0000
Epoch 43/300
140/140 [==============================] - 12s 82ms/step - loss: 8033843392112754688.0000 - val_loss: 7911180775406436352.0000
Epoch 44/300
140/140 [==============================] - 11s 81ms/step - loss: 9081903923022790656.0000 - val_loss: 8971991243152162816.0000
Epoch 45/300
140/140 [==============================] - 12s 82ms/step - loss: 10239744092896493568.0000 - val_loss: 10118807709445783552.0000
Epoch 46/300
140/140 [==============================] - 12s 83ms/step - loss: 11480463800004509696.0000 - val_loss: 11272904591982723072.0000
Epoch 47/300
140/140 [==============================] - 12s 83ms/step - loss: 12922274288228106240.0000 - val_loss: 12679005141559410688.0000
Epoch 48/300
140/140 [==============================] - 12s 84ms/step - loss: 14440855976837906432.0000 - val_loss: 14411765098190209024.0000
Epoch 49/300
140/140 [==============================] - 12s 84ms/step - loss: 16092970054106218496.0000 - val_loss: 15782474567492042752.0000
Epoch 50/300
140/140 [==============================] - 11s 82ms/step - loss: 17978044257021198336.0000 - val_loss: 17428357712365748224.0000
Epoch 51/300
140/140 [==============================] - 11s 81ms/step - loss: 19957860078366752768.0000 - val_loss: 19449063271636664320.0000
Epoch 52/300
140/140 [==============================] - 11s 80ms/step - loss: 22134736970712088576.0000 - val_loss: 21438266723260170240.0000
Epoch 53/300
140/140 [==============================] - 11s 80ms/step - loss: 24417683749788975104.0000 - val_loss: 23777754788283809792.0000
Epoch 54/300
140/140 [==============================] - 11s 80ms/step - loss: 26957898657579401216.0000 - val_loss: 26950012960184991744.0000
Epoch 55/300
140/140 [==============================] - 11s 80ms/step - loss: 29701901448508342272.0000 - val_loss: 29273421767164035072.0000
Epoch 56/300
140/140 [==============================] - 11s 80ms/step - loss: 32470889541666865152.0000 - val_loss: 32380171036282322944.0000
Epoch 57/300
140/140 [==============================] - 11s 80ms/step - loss: 35744571064160616448.0000 - val_loss: 34432158800875094016.0000
Epoch 58/300
140/140 [==============================] - 11s 80ms/step - loss: 39477833053901946880.0000 - val_loss: 38594313888332775424.0000
Epoch 59/300
140/140 [==============================] - 11s 80ms/step - loss: 43054016613475942400.0000 - val_loss: 42252604578222571520.0000
Epoch 60/300
140/140 [==============================] - 11s 80ms/step - loss: 47073039476252999680.0000 - val_loss: 46193271844357799936.0000
Epoch 61/300
140/140 [==============================] - 11s 79ms/step - loss: 51380301511274790912.0000 - val_loss: 49857539479456186368.0000
Epoch 62/300
140/140 [==============================] - 11s 80ms/step - loss: 73578966287049031680.0000 - val_loss: 95114080193506967552.0000
Epoch 63/300
140/140 [==============================] - 11s 80ms/step - loss: 126137829914090405888.0000 - val_loss: 126890599554930966528.0000
Epoch 64/300
140/140 [==============================] - 11s 81ms/step - loss: 145191759493029953536.0000 - val_loss: 140947539056698327040.0000
Epoch 65/300
140/140 [==============================] - 11s 79ms/step - loss: 156705722113797914624.0000 - val_loss: 150151612465462378496.0000
Epoch 66/300
140/140 [==============================] - 11s 78ms/step - loss: 168933681197364543488.0000 - val_loss: 165857282847219384320.0000
Epoch 67/300
140/140 [==============================] - 11s 78ms/step - loss: 181923768964747362304.0000 - val_loss: 177744797946454474752.0000
Epoch 68/300
140/140 [==============================] - 11s 79ms/step - loss: 195850675823367421952.0000 - val_loss: 190155328736790052864.0000
Epoch 69/300
140/140 [==============================] - 11s 79ms/step - loss: 210285750568066482176.0000 - val_loss: 206537752923489697792.0000
Epoch 70/300
140/140 [==============================] - 11s 79ms/step - loss: 225679493899069947904.0000 - val_loss: 224206289055338463232.0000
Epoch 71/300
140/140 [==============================] - 11s 80ms/step - loss: 242023760634239254528.0000 - val_loss: 235922808106221830144.0000
Epoch 72/300
140/140 [==============================] - 934s 7s/step - loss: 259300342861018431488.0000 - val_loss: 253334568690566299648.0000
Epoch 73/300
140/140 [==============================] - 11s 79ms/step - loss: 277439874589834346496.0000 - val_loss: 270541081240330567680.0000
Epoch 74/300
140/140 [==============================] - 11s 79ms/step - loss: 296605699268109402112.0000 - val_loss: 281020992757593800704.0000
Epoch 75/300
140/140 [==============================] - 11s 79ms/step - loss: 316959365940289470464.0000 - val_loss: 300832046043419901952.0000
Epoch 76/300
140/140 [==============================] - 11s 78ms/step - loss: 338192853020922871808.0000 - val_loss: 329560683988276740096.0000
Epoch 77/300
140/140 [==============================] - 11s 78ms/step - loss: 360538412550167986176.0000 - val_loss: 351810753131672764416.0000
Epoch 78/300
140/140 [==============================] - 11s 78ms/step - loss: 384654801526644015104.0000 - val_loss: 374909856357944393728.0000
Epoch 79/300
140/140 [==============================] - 11s 79ms/step - loss: 409462176386572615680.0000 - val_loss: 387308406869583724544.0000
Epoch 80/300
140/140 [==============================] - 11s 78ms/step - loss: 435474228962450735104.0000 - val_loss: 423723246819106357248.0000
Epoch 81/300
140/140 [==============================] - 11s 79ms/step - loss: 462715658683484733440.0000 - val_loss: 438362338145362509824.0000
Epoch 82/300
140/140 [==============================] - 11s 79ms/step - loss: 491863623974896271360.0000 - val_loss: 474452989290458644480.0000
Epoch 83/300
140/140 [==============================] - 11s 79ms/step - loss: 521712602695805698048.0000 - val_loss: 497868611128041406464.0000
Epoch 84/300
140/140 [==============================] - 11s 78ms/step - loss: 554028920693816557568.0000 - val_loss: 552752677965038354432.0000
Epoch 85/300
140/140 [==============================] - 11s 78ms/step - loss: 587034887569140613120.0000 - val_loss: 577442079625353101312.0000
Epoch 86/300
140/140 [==============================] - 11s 78ms/step - loss: 622060613324224069632.0000 - val_loss: 609653618563283419136.0000
Epoch 87/300
140/140 [==============================] - 11s 78ms/step - loss: 658377922194316460032.0000 - val_loss: 645952279716168728576.0000
Epoch 88/300
140/140 [==============================] - 11s 78ms/step - loss: 689101689958470516736.0000 - val_loss: 664218176117341683712.0000
Epoch 89/300
140/140 [==============================] - 11s 79ms/step - loss: 712720536729238372352.0000 - val_loss: 668376054104567316480.0000
Epoch 90/300
140/140 [==============================] - 11s 79ms/step - loss: 736622688064065503232.0000 - val_loss: 697641429645639286784.0000
Epoch 91/300
140/140 [==============================] - 11s 81ms/step - loss: 761716252606564663296.0000 - val_loss: 710633892358138101760.0000
Epoch 92/300
140/140 [==============================] - 12s 83ms/step - loss: 786623551083225546752.0000 - val_loss: 736182883412955103232.0000
Epoch 93/300
140/140 [==============================] - 12s 84ms/step - loss: 812168038538415177728.0000 - val_loss: 767104879929457639424.0000
Epoch 94/300
140/140 [==============================] - 12s 83ms/step - loss: 838510226077602807808.0000 - val_loss: 768993295548209430528.0000
Epoch 95/300
140/140 [==============================] - 12s 85ms/step - loss: 865192505757401088000.0000 - val_loss: 835306900105147187200.0000
Epoch 96/300
140/140 [==============================] - 12s 87ms/step - loss: 892559473318048038912.0000 - val_loss: 854022734256592125952.0000
Epoch 97/300
140/140 [==============================] - 12s 86ms/step - loss: 920385315459477536768.0000 - val_loss: 911726441488415981568.0000
Epoch 98/300
140/140 [==============================] - 12s 89ms/step - loss: 948772277966979727360.0000 - val_loss: 896994604157333667840.0000
Epoch 99/300
140/140 [==============================] - 12s 88ms/step - loss: 977894593851138506752.0000 - val_loss: 925630672019224788992.0000
Epoch 100/300
140/140 [==============================] - 13s 90ms/step - loss: 1007282903588288856064.0000 - val_loss: 976997955312826712064.0000
Epoch 101/300
140/140 [==============================] - 13s 90ms/step - loss: 1037899992336269574144.0000 - val_loss: 1002101371479510745088.0000
Epoch 102/300
140/140 [==============================] - 13s 90ms/step - loss: 1068569646536151007232.0000 - val_loss: 1023324584723494207488.0000
Epoch 103/300
140/140 [==============================] - 13s 91ms/step - loss: 1100316505471904120832.0000 - val_loss: 1051762705308013559808.0000
Epoch 104/300
140/140 [==============================] - 13s 92ms/step - loss: 1132165821299179913216.0000 - val_loss: 1088295624010266312704.0000
Epoch 105/300
140/140 [==============================] - 13s 95ms/step - loss: 1164246016976102621184.0000 - val_loss: 1126988792790029172736.0000
Epoch 106/300
140/140 [==============================] - 13s 93ms/step - loss: 1197211029242315276288.0000 - val_loss: 1128745196644703666176.0000
Epoch 107/300
140/140 [==============================] - 13s 94ms/step - loss: 1231605441809008820224.0000 - val_loss: 1186319495755984797696.0000
Epoch 108/300
140/140 [==============================] - 13s 93ms/step - loss: 1265784526018518712320.0000 - val_loss: 1207052520328026652672.0000
Epoch 109/300
140/140 [==============================] - 21s 151ms/step - loss: 1300272810489945260032.0000 - val_loss: 1222248509895704838144.0000
Epoch 110/300
140/140 [==============================] - 25s 179ms/step - loss: 1336351710054763724800.0000 - val_loss: 1269493240311658315776.0000
Epoch 111/300
140/140 [==============================] - 25s 179ms/step - loss: 1372607938854909902848.0000 - val_loss: 1305720054976738230272.0000
Epoch 112/300
140/140 [==============================] - 25s 179ms/step - loss: 1409111021209631326208.0000 - val_loss: 1365632285244578070528.0000
Epoch 113/300
140/140 [==============================] - 25s 179ms/step - loss: 1447033159659439521792.0000 - val_loss: 1358273544190943035392.0000
Epoch 114/300
140/140 [==============================] - 25s 179ms/step - loss: 1485377651311802056704.0000 - val_loss: 1417791005803946180608.0000
Epoch 115/300
140/140 [==============================] - 25s 179ms/step - loss: 1523708772902770835456.0000 - val_loss: 1449133244460677726208.0000
Epoch 116/300
140/140 [==============================] - 25s 179ms/step - loss: 1563550570693745704960.0000 - val_loss: 1444684110241300742144.0000
Epoch 117/300
140/140 [==============================] - 21s 151ms/step - loss: 1603516639686938329088.0000 - val_loss: 1513289554427360837632.0000
```

Had to cut off due to space limits

Comment: try using a smaller stepsize or another optimizer (like `keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-5)`)

Comment: It does not make any sense to ask a question when you have trained for only two epochs. You need to train for a lot more epochs.

Comment: Are you certain that the length of input_image_paths is the same as the length of target_image_paths? (The conditional tests when creating them are different). The two calls to random.Random(251).shuffle() might give different orderings if they're not the same length. Also isn't 270 images (as indicated in a comment) possibly too few samples to train an image classifier of this complexity? Might be worth looking for a way to use transfer learning if you have this few samples?

Comment: @DavidHarris Thank you for the comment. I just checked and they both have 640 in each. I believe that the comment is an outdated one from a previous model. I will take a look at transfer learning, thanks

Comment: OK. I think @AlbertoSinigaglia 's suggestion of reducing the learning rate is a good one. A small enough learning rate should lead to at least some loss reduction, unless something very fundamental is wrong. But it strikes me that what you're really trying to get the network to learn here might be a colour/brightness transformation that will be applied to every pixel in in original image in the same way. If that's true then there may be more appropriate architectures for the network.

Comment: I see. I found out that the issue was the function I was using to binarize the masks actually changed the values to 0 and 255, not 0 and 1. It works better now, but I will definitely look at more architectures as well